# pass by value and pass by reference for x and y

Tags: pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Given the pseudo code below, what will be the output of the program, when the two parameters x and y are passed by value, and when they are passed by reference?

```
int x = 1;
int y = 1; 
int count = 0;
while count < 3{
addnumbers(x, y);
println (x);
count++;
}

addnumbers(int x, int y){
x = x + y;
println (x);
}
```

Comment: I don't think your pseudo code does any passing of any kind.  It looks like you are trying to create a method numbers() inside your while loop, but it never gets called.

Comment: What language? And why is `distributed-computing` tagged?

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay It is just psuedocode, but the code is not correct.

Comment: It is a pseudocode which I need to solve but I dont know how the mechanism for call by value and call by reference works?

Comment: I have made an edit which will help answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Pass by Value:** In pass by value, when you pass a variable into a function, the function will use a copy of the variable, so the original is not affected.

```
2
1
2
1
2
1
```

**Pass by Reference:** In pass by reference, you pass the reference of the variable, so since both int x and int x inside the function reference the same thing, if you change one, the other one changes too.

```
2
2
3
3
4
4
```